# Which is the advantage of using Space over View

Tags: android, performance, view, android-view

I found that I'm using a `View` to make the space in my layouts and I thought to replace it with a `Space`.
So I asked myself if is there any gain to replace `View` with `Space` to make the space.

Space using the `View` widget :

```
<View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />
```

Space using the `Space` widget:

```
<Space
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />
```

So... is there any gain to use the `Space` view instead of the `View` for spacing in a layout?

Comment: Even if there was, I DOUBT it would be significant. The name may clarify the intent more clearly though.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

For the most part, they're exactly the same.  A Space sets its visibility to `View#INVISIBLE` by default so drawing operations are skipped.  Other than that, there isn't much of a difference.